# Rewrite PHP code without using variables

Tags: php, variables

**Example PHP code:**

```
<?php 
    $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( '8' );
?> 
 
<img src="<?php echo $image_attributes[0]; ?>" width="<?php echo $image_attributes[1]; ?>" height="<?php echo $image_attributes[2]; ?>">
```

Now, lets say, I don't want to use the `$image_attributes` variable at all, and directly employ `wp_get_attachment_image_src( '8' );` instead of `$image_attributes[0];`, `$image_attributes[1];` and `$image_attributes[2];` later on with the img tag.

In that case, how should I modify the code?

### WHY?

Let me explain by example (my real use case).

```
<?php 
    $attachment_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( '8' ); // returns an array
?> 
 
<media:content url="<?php echo $attachment_attributes[0]; ?>" width="<?php echo $attachment_attributes[1]; ?>" height="<?php echo $attachment_attributes[2]; ?>" type="image/jpeg">
```

How do I do the same, like when I am coding it like this?

```
foreach ( $attachments as $att_id => $attachment ) {
    $attachment_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( '8' );
    
    // Should it be done like this? If not, how do I do it?
    $output .= '<media:content height="' . $attachment_attributes[0]; . '" type="image/jpeg">';

    if ( $captiontag && trim($attachment->post_excerpt) ) {
        $output .= "
            <{$captiontag}>" . wptexturize($attachment->post_excerpt) . "</{$captiontag}>";
    }
    $output .= '
        </media:content>';
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. What's the problem with using variables?

Comment: @MartinBean I have an instance where my knowledge is not sufficient to use variables (it gets complex). So, I want to try the other way around

Comment: @its_me, variables are the most basic of all programming concepts. You can't do much without learning about them.

Comment: @its_me Variables are an essential part of programming. If you can't handle variables, then you're in the wrong game. As far as I'm aware, it's nigh on impossible to program *without* variables.

Comment: Agreed ^^. Give it a try, it's the more efficient way. The other way makes the server consume more CPU than normal.

Comment: Variables are essential for readability, but in this case, they're also quite useful for performance. I do not consider it premature optimization to avoid calling `wp_get_attachment_image_src` twice to get the unchanging value in two different indices. Call it once, assign it to the variable, and have at it.

Comment: Sorry, not seeing the problem with the variables in your explanation. Is there an error you're getting, or something wrong with the contents of $output?

Comment: @rrehbein I don't know how to use `$image_attributes[0]; ?>`, `$image_attributes[1]; ?>`  and so on, with the `$output`. Can it be written like this? `$output .= '<media:content height="' . $image_attributes[0]; . '" type="image/jpeg">';`

Comment: Could it be that your actual problem is the syntax? Can you see the red parts in your above posting? You might just need an editor with syntax highlighting as well. You're confused about string quoting. -- The original confusing variables issue could be resolved with concise var names, and HEREDOC usage, or at least short tags.

Comment: @its_me:  It is very important to say what your GOAL is, not the steps you are trying to take to _reach_ that goal.  Had you from the start said _This code is too complex and ugly, is there an easier way to write it_ it would have gotten you to your answer **much** faster.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher Learnt that the hard way (down/close-votes). Will make sure I explain the question better next time. Thanks for the advise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure why your trying to avoid variables, but you may be able to get away with something like:

```
<?php

vprintf(
    '<img src="%s" width="%d" height="%d">',
    wp_get_attachment_image_src( '8' )
);
```

Or, from the code from 'Why'

```
<?php

foreach ( $attachments as $att_id => $attachment ) {
    $attachment_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( '8' );

    $output .= '
        <media:content
          url="' . $attachment_attributes[0] . '"
          width="' . $attachment_attributes[1] . '"
          height="' . $attachment_attributes[2] . '"
          type="image/jpeg">';

    if ( $captiontag && trim($attachment->post_excerpt) ) {
        $output .= "
            <{$captiontag}>" . wptexturize($attachment->post_excerpt) . "</{$captiontag}>";
    }
    $output .= '
        </media:content>';
}
```

Comment: This is slower and more confusing, but does what the OP wants.